# Serialize/Deserialize Json DateTime in Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, neo4jclient

I use Neo4jClient to use Neo4j, I use cypher code for CRUD entity , Follow code :

```
_graphClient.Cypher.Merge("(n:Movie { Id:101 })")
            .Set("n.Key = 55,n.DateTime='" +DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()+"'").ExecuteWithoutResults();

_graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(n:Movie)-[r:RelName]-(m:Movie)")
            .Where((EntityNode n) => n.Id == 20)
            .Return.......

public class EntityNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

> ERROR :Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied.Can't deserialize **DateTime**.

On other hand i use jsonconvertor in **different ways**, for example :

```
   _graphClient.Cypher.Merge("(n:Movie { Id:101 })")
                .Set("n.Key = 55,n.DateTime=" +JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.UtcNow)).ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I still have the **ERROR**

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a proper parameter:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Merge("(n:Movie { Id:101 })")
    .Set("n.Key = {key}, n.DateTime = {time}")
    .WithParams(new {
        key = 55,
        time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

This way, Neo4jClient will do the serialization for you, and you don't introduce lots of security and performance issues.

This is in the doco here: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#parameters

Comment: If i use string instead of datetime !working! but can't serialize class for datetime! i have error

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue recently its because of date time value coming from neo.

I have stored the date time in neo as epoch time but while retrieving i used long in the class. because  of this its given me the above error.

Try using string for the above date time.

Hope this helps you.